# Office JS API fails on Outlook 2016 on Mac

Tags: javascript, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I am developing a Outlook web add-in in which I open a task pane for the currently selected appointment item.

I am using this code snippet for reading the itemId of the appointment item.

```
itemId = Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId;                    

                if (itemId === null || itemId == undefined) {
                    Office.context.mailbox.item.saveAsync(function (result) {
                        itemId = result.value;
```

This code works fine in OWA, Outlook for Windows. However it fails to read the itemId on Outlook for Mac. I am getting the itemId as 'undefined'.

Answer (score 1):

This is known limitation of saveAsync() and [documented here](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.5/Office.context.mailbox.item#saveasyncoptions-callback):

> Note: The following clients have different behavior for saveAsync on appointments in compose mode:
>
> - **Mac Outlook does not support saveAsync on a meeting in compose mode. Calling saveAsync on a meeting in Mac Outlook will return an error.**
> - Outlook on the web always sends an invitation or update when saveAsync is called on an appointment in compose mode.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification Mark. I was using saveAsync() as a workaround. However , the statement Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId;     also returns undefined on Outlook on Mac.

Comment: This is documented a little further up: "The itemId property is not available in compose mode"